# Spring: File upload from class to Rest web service

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, spring-mvc

I created a Spring web service file exhange, so the client can download one file from the server (streaming because file can be big), and now I hava to realize file upload from the client (client is a java class and it calls web service and upload the file ).
For the first step, download part, I used this code:
server side(this code will be improved)

```
@Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<byte[]> getAcquisition(HttpServletResponse resp,@RequestParam(value="filePath", required = true) String filePath){

        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        File toServeUp = new File(filePath);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(toServeUp);
            resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream"); //.exe file
            resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+toServeUp.getName()+"\"");
            Long fileSize = toServeUp.length();
            resp.setContentLength(fileSize.intValue());
            outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            String msg = "ERROR: Could not send file.";
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            //If I set NOT_FOUND on the client I have to catch 404 exception
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(msg.getBytes(), headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }finally{
            //close the streams to prevent memory leaks
            try {
                if (inputStream!=null)inputStream.close();
                if (outputStream!=null){
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();           
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                String msg = "ERROR: Could not close stream.";
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                //If I set NOT_FOUND on the client I have to catch 404 exception
                return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(msg.getBytes(), headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

client side

```
@Override
public Response getJsonFromRest(String url, String... queryParams) {
    try{
        Response response;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        if (queryParams.length!=0){
            String urlParametrized = addQueryParam(url, queryParams);
            response = restTemplate.getForObject(urlParametrized, Response.class);
        }
        else{
            response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Response.class);
        }
        return response;    
    }catch(Exception e){
        ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
        LOG.error("Threw exception in FileServicesImpl::getJsonFromRest :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
        return new Response(false, false,"Error with web service request!" , errorResponse);            
    }
}
```

Now for the file upload I should use the above code but reversing client-server code. So on the client I may use

```
String response= restTemplate.postForEntity(serverIp + "/client/file/?toStorePath={toStorePath}", responseSend, String.class, toStorePath);
```

but how can I set `HttpServletResponse` and send stream of file to my server?
Thanks

***UPDATE*** For the moment this code works but I would like to use spring and not http method
On the client

```
@Override
public Response sendFile(String serverIp, String toStorePath, String filePath) {
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()){
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverIp + "ATS/client/file");
        File file = new File(filePath);

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file);
        ContentBody cbPath= new StringBody(toStorePath,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        builder.addPart("file", cbFile);
        builder.addPart("toStorePath",cbPath);
        httppost.setEntity(builder.build());
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine());
        if (resEntity != null) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Response response = mapper.readValue(resEntity.getContent(), Response.class);
            EntityUtils.consume(resEntity) ;
            return response;
        }
        //It should never be thrown 
        else return new Response(false, false, "Error with server response" , null); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
        LOG.error("Threw exception in FileServicesImpl::sendFile :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
        return new Response(false, false,"Error sending the file!" , errorResponse);
    }
```

Instead on the server:

```
    @Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Response storeAcquisition(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("toStorePath") String toStorePath){
    String name= file.getOriginalFilename();
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            file.transferTo(new File(toStorePath + "/" + name));
            return new Response(true, true, "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + toStorePath, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
            LOG.error("Threw exception in MatlabClientControllerImpl::storeAcquisition :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
            return new Response(false, false, "You failed to upload " + name, errorResponse);
        }
    } else {
        return new Response(false, false, "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.", null);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I updated with working code, but I would like to use spring library